# Android studio cannot find class Futures for wearos tiles

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os, wear-os-tiles

My intentions is to create tiles for wearos. The problem I get is that the class needed for this, "Futures", is not found. It should be located in com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures but android studio cannot find it there.

My build error states as follows:

```
/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/yyy/app/src/main/java/com/xxx/yyy/services/TileService.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Futures
  location: package com.google.common.util.concurrent
```

This leads to the obvious fact that I cannot use this class in my code so the rest of my errors only say "cannot find symbol method/variable Futures".

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.2.0'

    /* for tiling: */
    // Use to implement support for wear tiles
    implementation 'androidx.wear.tiles:tiles:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0"

    // Use to preview wear tiles in our own app
    debugImplementation 'androidx.wear.tiles:tiles-renderer:1.0.0'

    // Use to fetch tiles from a tile provider in our tests
    testImplementation 'androidx.wear.tiles:tiles-testing:1.0.0'
}
```

TileService.java:

```
package com.elvigo.spotprice.services;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.wear.tiles.LayoutElementBuilders.Text;
import androidx.wear.tiles.LayoutElementBuilders.Layout;
import androidx.wear.tiles.RequestBuilders;
import androidx.wear.tiles.ResourceBuilders;
import androidx.wear.tiles.TileBuilders.*;
import androidx.wear.tiles.TimelineBuilders.TimelineEntry;
import androidx.wear.tiles.TimelineBuilders.Timeline;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures; // <-- Error here

public class TileService extends androidx.wear.tiles.TileService {
    private static final String RESOURCES_VERSION = "1";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ListenableFuture<Tile> onTileRequest(
            @NonNull RequestBuilders.TileRequest requestParams
    ) {
        return Futures(new Tile.Builder()
                .setResourcesVersion(RESOURCES_VERSION)
                .setTimeline(new Timeline.Builder()
                        .addTimelineEntry(new TimelineEntry.Builder()
                                .setLayout(new Layout.Builder()
                                        .setRoot(new Text.Builder()
                                                .setText("Hello world!").build()
                                        ).build()
                                ).build()
                        ).build()
                ).build()
        ).build();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected ListenableFuture<ResourceBuilders.Resources> onResourcesRequest(
            @NonNull RequestBuilders.ResourcesRequest requestParams
    ) {
        return Futures.immediateFuture(new ResourceBuilders.Resources.Builder()
                .setVersion(RESOURCES_VERSION)
                .build()
        );
    }
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava futures lives here

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava
implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-android")
```

kotlinx-coroutines-guava happens to depend on it, so use that if you also want coroutines.

Answer (score 3):

Futures can be found here:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-guava:1.5.1'
```

Comment: Alright, this worked, but how can this work when I use java and not kotlin? I mean I'm implementing guava group from kotlin right?

Comment: no, you can use kotlin